# Why is iText embedding font even if I have specified not to embed?

Tags: fonts, itext

I am using Noto fonts to create pdf and looking embedding of a font vs not embedding them. My code

```
   FontFactory.register("c:/temp/fonts/NotoSansCJKsc-Regular.otf", "my_nato_font");
   Font myBoldFont = FontFactory.getFont("my_nato_font", BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
```

When I create the pdf and do a CTRL + D, I can see that the fonts have been embedded.

However once I go with option

```
   FontFactory.register("c:/temp/fonts/NotoSansCJKsc-Regular.otf", "my_nato_font");
   Font myBoldFont = FontFactory.getFont("my_nato_font");
```

The size of file is reduced and the fonts are not embedded. Now I cannot see the Chinese characters which I have added to the pdf.

My questions

1. Why does NOT_EMBED option still embed the font ?
2. Since Noto fonts are open sourced by google and supported by adobe [Introducing Source Hans](http://blog.typekit.com/2014/07/15/introducing-source-han-sans/) , I would assume that end user should be able to view the documents even with out the need to embed them. Is my understanding wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using Identity-H, the font **shall** be embedded because if the `embedded` parameter wouldn't be ignored, iText would be creating a PDF that is in violation with ISO-32000-1:

> **Section 9.7.5.2:**
>
> The Identity-H and Identity-V CMaps shall not be used with a non-embedded font.

Adobe owns a whole lot of patents with respect to PDF software. Adobe grants the right to any one to use these patents for free *on condition that you create PDF files that are compliant with the PDF specification.*

If you would tweak iText so that it would not embed fonts with Identity-H CMaps, you would be in violation with the PDF specification and that could bring about some patent violations too.

Comment: Perfect. Explain everything. Thanks